# Keep keyboard opened after presenting new viewController

Tags: ios, swift

How to keep the keyboard opened if presenting new viewController?

I have 2 viewcontrollers: `firstVC`, `secondVC`. `firstVC` has textfield and `secondVC` has it also. Now if I present `secondVC` from `firstVC` I want the keyboard to be opened but it dismisses it.

According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621385-disablesautomatickeyboarddismiss) I tried overriding the `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal`  which is not working for some reason:

```
override var disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal: Bool {
    return true
}
```

What else I should do? I do not want that it dismisses then assign `becomeFirstResponder()` because it makes nasty animation.

I know that if you want to keep keyboard opened if you present for example an `UIAlertView` then you can do this:

```
let rootViewController: UIViewController = (UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController)!
        rootViewController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I believe you can open the keyboard on secondVC in the -viewWillAppear by selecting a textfield and [textfield becomeFirstResponder]

Comment: that doesn't do want I want. I want the keyboard to be not dismissable. Like Uber's phone authentication views. They keep the keyboard on view even after segue without the dismiss animation.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: @Crashalot Nope , I couldn't find working solution. I remember googling days and trying different solutions but non of them worked as I wanted. Do you know any other application that has implemented this? It is very interesting question and I wouod like to reinvestigate time in that.

Comment: No, unfortunately. The only other option is to use a XIB instead of a view controller?

Comment: If you use xib then maybe it is possible yes.

Comment: This also seems like a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189343/prevent-keyboard-from-dismissing-while-changing-views

Answer (score 0):

`txtcode.becomeFirstResponder()`    In txtcode replace your textfield name and give the delegates for the same

Comment: that doesn't do want I want. I want the keyboard to be not dismissable. Like Uber's phone authentication views. They keep the keyboard on view even after segue.